# Position of elements in list

Tags: coq

I am using index function to find the value of element at any location in the list nat. Plz guide me in proving the second part of the lemma, which is illustrated below

```
 Fixpoint index(n: nat) (m: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
match l with
| nil => 0
| cons h tl => match (eqb n m) with
| true => h
| false => index (succ n) m tl
 end
  end.
  Theorem a_ref:forall (a:nat),
    a <= a.
 Proof.
    intros. eauto.
  Qed.
Theorem n_leq_0 :forall (n:nat),
  n <= 0.
  Proof.
  intros. induction n.
+ simpl. apply a_ref.
+ Admitted.
Theorem n_le_index:forall (n:nat) (l:list nat),
 n <= index (succ (succ 0)) 0 l.
Proof.
intros. induction l as [| l'].
+ simpl. apply n_leq_0.
+ simpl in *.  inversion IHl.  
rewrite <- H.
```

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you want cannot be proved:

```
Fixpoint index(n: nat) (m: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
match l with
| nil => 0
| cons h tl => match (Nat.eqb n m) with
| true => h
| false => index (Nat.succ n) m tl
 end
  end.

Theorem n_le_index:forall (n:nat) (l:list nat),
 n <= index (Nat.succ (Nat.succ 0)) 0 l.
Admitted.

Require Import Omega.

Goal False.
pose proof (n_le_index 10 nil).
simpl in H.
omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: Theorem is sub goal ,when I am solving another theorem i.e  `Theorem index_diff : forall (n m l':nat) (l:list nat),
(index n m (l'::l))<= index (succ n) m l.`.You are saying theorem can not prove.It means I am going in wrong direction ,when solving the above theorem

Comment: This other statement is also false. For example, take n = m = 0, l' = 1 and l = [].